# SignalR: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to invoke 'ListData' due to an error on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, signalr

I'm trying to display data from a database using an Id. The query string works, but when I use a parameter in the SignalR Hub it throws me the uncaught error. I want to take the parameter from the controller and pass it on to the id. So when someone types in the id in the url the ListData method takes that id and uses it for the query. I thought I could use `await _Sig.Clients.All.SendAsync("ListData", id);` in the controller but that's not working.

controller:

```
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly DBContext _Context;
        private readonly IHubContext<SignalHub> _Sig;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, Context Context,  IHubContext<SignalHub> Sig)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _Context = Context;
            _Sig = Sig;
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> Message(string id)
        {






            await _Sig.Clients.All.SendAsync("ListData", id);
            

            return View();
        }
```

SignalR Hub:

```
        private readonly DBContext _Context;
        public SignalHub(DBContext Context)
        {
            _Context = Context;
        }

public async Task ListData(string id)
        {

            var viewModel = _Context.UserMessage.Where(x => x.MessageId == id).Select(x => new 
            MessagesModel { Id = x.Id, Message = x.Message, MessageId = x.MessageId }).ToList();

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveData", viewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a SignalR application, the server has no information about the methods implemented by the client; when the server invokes a client method, the method name and parameter data are sent to the client, and are only executed if the format specified by the server exists.

Here are your possible problems:

1. If the name or signature of the called method does not exactly match the appropriate method on the client, the call will fail

Verify that the method name invoked by the server matches the method name on the client. Also, SignalR creates hub proxies using camelCase methods, which is appropriate in JavaScript, so a method called ListData on the server will be called listData in the client proxy. If you are using the HubName property in server-side code, verify that the name used matches the name used to create the hub on the client. If you are not using the HubName property, verify that the name of the hub in the JavaScript client is camelCase, eg chatHub instead of ChatHub.

2. Duplicate method names on the client

Verify that there are no duplicate methods on your client, only capitalization differs. If your client application has a method named listData, verify that there is also a method named ListData.

3. Missing JSON parser on the client

SignalR requires a JSON parser to serialize calls between server and client. If your client does not have a built-in JSON parser (like Internet Explorer 7), you will need to include one in your application. You can download a JSON parser.

4. Hybrid Hub and PersistentConnection Syntax

SignalR uses two communication modes: Hubs and PersistentConnections. The syntax for calling the two communication models is different in client code. If you added the hub in your server code, make sure all of your client code uses the correct hub syntax.